# Lambdify error when sympy array contains number

Tags: python, symbolic-computation

This example is a dummy example, but it describes exactly whats goes on in my problem.

As a result from some sympy calculation and manipulation i got two arrays

```
array_1 = ([f_1(x,y)      0         f_3(x,y) ])
array_2 = ([g_1(x,y)   g_2(x,y)     g_3(x,y) ])
```

where f_n(x,y) and g_n(x,y) are complex functions. When I print them to se what kind of creature they are, they both are on the form

```
Matrix([[#, #, #]])
```

as expected from a sympy matrix.

Furthermore I use lambdify to convert the arrays by

```
lambda_array_1 = lambdify([x, y], array_1, 'numpy' )
lambda_array_2 = lambdify([x, y], array_2, 'numpy' )
```

Then I let

```
x = 1
y = 1
x_array = np.array([x], dtype = complex)
y_array = np.array([y], dtype = complex)

pythonarray_1 = lambda_array_1(x_array , y_array )
pythonarray_1 = np.reshape(pythonarray_1, 3) 

pythonarray_2 = lambda_array_2(x_array , y_array )
pythonarray_2 = np.reshape(pythonarray_2, 3)
```

When I then print the two pythonarrays I get

```
pythonarray_1 = array([array([# + #j]), array([# + #j]), array([# + #j])], dtype=object)

pythonarray_2 = array([# + #j, # + #j, # + #j ])
```

where I need the arrays on the form as in pythonarray_2.

What is wrong with pythonarray_1, how can I fix it, and why does it happen?

Comment: You can try using ``np.array(array_1).astype(np.complex)``. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069864/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-sympy-matrix-to-a-numpy-array-matrix) question in StackOverflow discuss it.